# Increasing the number of history items in firefox's history panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, history

Firefox displays the 15 most recently visited sites in its history panel (cf. figure). I'd like to see more, so I can easily scroll through that list rather than having to click "Show All History".

I already tried to find a Firefox Add-on and searched the about:config thing for "history" and "15" but was unable to identify anything helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a addon to do this: [History Submenus Ⅱ](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/history-submenus-2/)

> Add sub-menus to History Menu for previous days' history.

[image]

Works in Firefox 30.0